# How to properly use image as vertex labels to draw graphs?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I imported an image and used it as vertex labels to draw a graph.
The problem is I cannot control the size of the image.
So it looks like this.

[image]

Here's my code. `VertexLabelStyle` does not seem to do anything.

```
mafia = Import["mafioso.png"];
gnp = RandomGraph[{10, 12},
  VertexLabels -> Placed[mafia, Center],
  VertexStyle -> LightYellow, 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[20],
  VertexSize -> 0.5,
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  ImageMargins -> 10,
  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding",
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle",
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give your image an explicit size with [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane). I don't have your mafia png, so here's a waterskiing icon instead:

```
water = Pane[
    Entity["Icon","Waterskiing"]["Image"],
    20
]
```

[image]

Then, use this image in your graph:

```
SeedRandom[1];
gnp = RandomGraph[{10, 12},
  VertexLabels -> Placed[water, Center],
  VertexStyle -> LightYellow, 
  VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[20],
  VertexSize -> 0.5,
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  ImageMargins -> 10,
  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding",
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle",
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"
]
```

[image]